# C# What is the difference between creating a static object outside a class VS creating it inside a class?

Tags: c#

I want to understand the difference between 3 sets of snippets below:

```
private static FirstObject o = new FirstObject();
public class ClassA
{
}

//-----------------------------------------------------

public class ClassA
{
    private static FirstObject o = new FirstObject();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------

public class ClassA
{
    private static FirstObject o;

    public ClassA
    { 
        o = new FirstObject();
    }
}
```

Please help me understand in terms of scope, memory, performance and usage of these.

Thank you.

Comment: Those are some weird comparison criteria. Also, where is the static variable supposed to be in the first example, if outside `ClassA`?

Comment: if it is a collection i.e. a dictionary then i can add objects in it.

Answer (score 5):

1. Invalid, as you can't have a variable outside of object
2. The proper way - the class has a static member, which is initialized when the class is accessed for the first time
3. Very bad, because every time when new object is created the static object will be recreated.

Comment: The only scenario I can think of where the first use would be valid is if `ClassA` is a nested class (making the object unrelated to that class). But, well, that's not a very good assumption.

Comment: I had the same thought, @BoltClock.

Answer (score 1):

The first option will not compile.  A static variable in C# must be scoped to a class or struct.

The second option is the preferred mechanism.

The third option is wrong because this creates a new `FirstObject` each time an instance of `ClassA` is created, which is almost certainly **not** what you want.

A fourth option would be to leverage a static constructor, e.g.,

```
public class ClassA
{
    private static FirstObject o;
    static ClassA
    {
        o = new FirstObject();
    }
}
```

This option is useful if there is some special construction constraints for `FirstObject`.  In this example, though, choose option 2 over option 4.  Just know that option 4 exists.

Comment: So with a static constructor it will only be called once upon creation? Keeping object o in it's current state regardless of new instances of ClassA?

Comment: A static constructor will be invoked, at most, one time.  It is guaranteed to occur prior to any instance of the class being created or any members being accessed.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Three cases below...

1. Assuming a typo here missing some outer construct... "o" is declared so that it will be globally accessible, as a single object, to the entire application. It will have one common set of all properties and data. It can be access directly by "Namespace.o"
2. "o" is declared so that it will be globally accessible, as a single object, to the entire application, However it is only accessible through another defined instance of "ClassA". Each separate instance of ClassA will have the same, single "o" object with the same properties and data.
3. This doesn't look right to me, I'm assuming "ol" is supposed to "o;". Even with this the code looks like its missing something. if the Line "o = new FirstObject" is correct it is not accessible in this fashion.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong.  1) Even with an outer construct, you cannot access it using "Namespace.o".  2) "o" is not globally accessible in this case.  3) There is nothing wrong syntactically with this option nor is there anything that prevents "o" from being used in this fashion, even though it is a very poor example.

Comment: Yeah I was typing pretty quick. Should have been more clear indicating the the outer construct included a class. I meant "Qualifier...o" type of thing, was meant to be sort of Pseudo. I did try number 3's format in the editor and it didn't seem to work for me.